# Is it possible to model inheritance?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

My primary source of information for this question comes from a tutorial by James Shore at this address: http://www.objectplayground.com/ ... After rewatching the video several times I took away enough to string together a series of classes, but I still don't really get what's going on under the hood. The way James explained it classical model inheritance (which I assume refers to the use of classes to organize data, rather than an older way of doing things) works like this:

When any function definition statement is evaluated, two objects are created. The first object created is the constructor (which I'm calling `cStruct` for the purposes of this question), and is identifiable by its member called prototype which according to him and many other sources points to the *Function Object Prototype*, or `Function.prototype`. But then it gets weird because the second object created is the prototype (or `proType`) which in turn is identifiable by its own member called constructor that points back to `cStruct`, as well as having it's own prototype member that points to the *Object Object Prototype*, or just `Object.prototype`. Okay, simple enough (ha!), but then he (and other sources) continue; When one class extends another, we abandon the extending (newer / narrower) classes `proType` exchanging it for a fresh one which actually points to the extended (original / older / broader) classes `proType`.

Okay, so by this description I have attempted to recreate the inheritance model using only objects with `null` prototypes as building blocks, so that I could inspect the results in the console without having to sift through all the stuff I don't understand yet. **Basically, I'm looking for the smoking gun of inheritance; proof that it's not just a magic trick**. It seems it should be possible but once the logic is established in code form, it not so surprisingly fails to deliver inherited properties. You'll see what I mean.

**Common Practice** --- Three classes

```
function ExampleClass_A (  ) {  }
function ExampleClass_B (  ) {  }
function ExampleClass_C (  ) {  }
```

**Literal Interpretation**

**NOTE** *These are literally emulated classes. They demonstrate what I understand is going on behind the scenes when classes are authored. On that note, the `c` variable can almost be ignored until we start extending classes later*

```
a = Object.create( null );
b = Object.create( null );
c = Object.create( null );  // this represents the Object Prototype
cStruct_A               = a;
proType_A               = b;
proType_A.prototype     = c;
cStruct_A.prototype     = b;
proType_A.constructor   = a;
delete a; delete b;

a = Object.create( null );
b = Object.create( null );
cStruct_B               = a;
proType_B               = b;
proType_B.prototype     = c;
cStruct_B.prototype     = b;
proType_B.constructor   = a;
delete a; delete b;

a = Object.create( null );
b = Object.create( null );
cStruct_C               = a;
proType_C               = b;
proType_C.prototype     = c;
cStruct_C.prototype     = b;
proType_C.constructor   = a;
delete a; delete b; delete c;
```

**Common Practice** --- linear class extension

**EDIT** *@Vog, I'm not sure what object composition is, but if I had to guess I'd say it was an alternative pattern of class extension / instantiation to the linear one that I have authored in this question, where-in I would have to assume some form of inheritance was taking place anyway. I of course am not prepared to embrace one pattern over another as I'm am simply trying to understand how the mechanism that makes these patterns viable practices in the first place even works.*

```
ExampleClass_B.prototype = Object.create( ExampleClass_A.prototype );
ExampleClass_C.prototype = Object.create( ExampleClass_B.prototype );
```

**Literal Interpretation**

**NOTE** *If I understand this correctly, for inheritance to work the `proType` of all subclasses subsequent to the master class or one another must point to the `proType` of its parent class. So here we do away with two of three of the classes `proType`'s and replace them with ones that have been pointed to the appropriate "supsequent" location.*

```
a                       = Object.create( null );
a.prototype             = proType_A;
a.constructor           = cStruct_B;
alt_proType_B           = a;
cStruct_B.prototype     = alt_proType_B;
delete proType_B;
delete a;

a                       = Object.create( null );
a.prototype             = alt_proType_B;
a.constructor           = cStruct_C;
alt_proType_C           = a;
cStruct_C.prototype     = alt_proType_C;
delete proType_C;
delete a;
```

**Common Practice** --- instantiation

```
var exampleInstance_W = new ExampleClass_A();   //  
var exampleInstance_R = new ExampleClass_B();   //  randomly chosen names
var exampleInstance_T = new ExampleClass_C();   //
```

**Literal Interpretation**

```
a = Object.create( null );
a.prototype             = proType_A;
nstance_W               = a;
delete a;

a = Object.create( null );
a.prototype             = alt_proType_B;
nstance_R               = a;
delete a;

a = Object.create( null );
a.prototype             = alt_proType_C;
nstance_T               = a;
delete a;
```

**Common Practice** --- assignments

```
ExampleClass_A.prototype.prop_a = "test a,";
ExampleClass_B.prototype.prop_b = "test b,";
ExampleClass_C.prototype.prop_c = "test c";
```

**Literal Interpretation**

**NOTE** *here's where I start to see that something might be wrong*

```
cStruct_A.prototype.prop_a = "test a,";
cStruct_B.prototype.prop_b = "test b,";
cStruct_C.prototype.prop_c = "test c";

//  proType_A.prop_a = "test a";    //
//  proType_B.prop_b = "test b";    //  Kind of cool that this works
//  proType_C.prop_c = "test c";    //
```

**Test** --- common practice

```
console.log(
    exampleInstance_T.prop_a,  //  successful log
    exampleInstance_T.prop_b,  //  successful log
    exampleInstance_T.prop_c,  //  successful log
);
```

**Test** --- literal interpretation

**NOTE** *Now for the culmination of all that effort. How confusing that these logs yield different results...*

```
console.log(
    nstance_T.prototype.prop_a,     //  unsuccessful log
    nstance_T.prototype.prop_b,     //  unsuccessful log
    nstance_T.prototype.prop_c,     //  successful log
);

console.log(
    nstance_R.prototype.prop_a,     //  unsuccessful log
    nstance_R.prototype.prop_b,     //  successful log
    nstance_R.prototype.prop_c,     //  unsuccessful log
);

console.log(
    nstance_W.prototype.prop_a,     //  successful log
    nstance_W.prototype.prop_b,     //  unsuccessful log
    nstance_W.prototype.prop_c,     //  unsuccessful log
);

console.log(                        //  Kind of lame that this does't work
    nstance_W.prop_a,               //  
    nstance_R.prop_b,               //  I mean it makes sense when you follow the
    nstance_T.prop_c,               //  established logic, but at the same time
);                                  //  it means that I'm missing something.
```

---

In other words, if each ***Literal Interpretation*** code block is just emulating the ***Common Practice*** code block above it, why doesn't `nstance_t` have access to `.prop_a` and `.prop_b`? Is it something to do with my configuration? Am I missing the point? Help me out guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you confused about the difference between `.prototype` and `Object.get/setPrototypeOf`?

Comment: Btw, [the `delete` operator does not do what you think it does](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/). Drop all `delete` statements in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't `nstance_t` have access to `.prop_a` and `.prop_b`? Is it something to do with my configuration? Am I missing the point?

It seems like you expected that `.prototype` sets up the inheritance chain of an object. It does not, it's just an ordinary property, and assigning it doesn't do anything magic.

The actual reference to the object (or `null`) that an object is inheriting from is internal, often denoted as *[[prototype]]*. You need to call `Object.getPrototypeOf(…)` to access it. For setting it, you can use `Object.create`, `Object.setPrototypeOf`, or `new`.

I believe this is the code that you are looking for:

**Common practice - ES6**

```
class A {}
class B extends B {}
const instance = new B
```

**Common practice - ES5**

```
function A() {}
function B() {}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype)
B.prototype.constructor = B
const instance = new B
```

**Literal Interpretation** (of the object relationships, ignoring the constructor calls)

```
A_prototype = Object.create(Object.prototype)
A_constructor = new Function(…)
A_prototype.constructor = A_constructor
A_constructor.prototype = A_prototype

B_prototype = Object.create(A_constructor.prototype)
B_constructor = new Function(…)
B_prototype.constructor = B_constructor
B_constructor.prototype = B_prototype

instance = Object.create(B_constructor.prototype)
```

You can now assign properties on `A_prototype`/`A_constructor.prototype` and `B_prototype`/`B_constructor.prototype` and see them being inherited on `instance`.

Comment: +1 for workable code that address my question directly! ... When I copy and paste your code into the console and assign properties, they are indeed accessible by `nStance_T`. But when I try to break up your code into long form, as in *class creation* > *class extension* >  *instantiation*, I somehow lose *all* successful logs. When I return from work I will update my question to show the changes I made based on your answer.

Comment: @Musixauce3000 I think creating the objects as `Object.create(null)` and later assigning them a prototype is what doesn't work in your code. E.g. in `proType_A.prototype     = c;` - a prototype object does not have a `.prototype` property! I think you meant to do `Object.setPrototypeOf(proType_A, c);`, which I abbreviated into starting with `Object.create(c)` right away (which is what the engine itself does as well).

Comment: I think I understand ... perhaps my confusion then is coming from the fact that I've read that `Object.create( null )` returns an object with no prototype i.e. *with `null` as it's prototype* --- and from that inferred inaccurately that the likes of `ExampleClass_B.prototype = Object.create( ExampleClass_A.prototype );` basically just reconfigured the "`proType`" prototype object of one class to point to an object having its own `.prototype` member pointing to another classes prototype ... If that makes any sense. I think this is why I need to literally see the inheritance happening lol

Comment: Yes, that reconfigures the "proType" of one class, but not to an object having a `.prototype` member, rather to an object inheriting from the "proType" of the other class.

Comment: Just a crazy thought here... are you telling me that inheritance has nothing to do with `.prototype`?

Comment: I just ran some tests in the console and found that every time I have successful inheritance the `.__proto__` member can be found if you expand the objects in chrome... But I've been using `Object.create( null )` specifically to avoid having to sift through stuff I didn't understand, like the `.__proto__` member... Are you telling me that `.__proto__` is responsible for inheritance?

Comment: I just took a screenshot of the results of a small script I ran to test `.__proto__`; the results were in unexpected. https://i.imgur.com/QnE7DjR.png ... can you help me understand why this didn't work? and why the expanded objects look slightly different?

Comment: Yes, the `.prototype` property only exists on constructor functions and is relevant only for `new` calls. It does not itself affect inheritance between two objects. That's the internal *[[prototype]]* link, accessed using `Object.getPrototypeOf`/`Object.setPrototypeOf`. In the debugger it is shown as `__proto__` for compatibility reasons (the `.__proto__` getter/setter is deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

While I applaud your curiosity to build such a thing, please be aware that inheritance is a well-known anti-pattern. There are some more aspects of (classic) object-oriented programming that are questioned "today" (in the sense of: the last decade, if not longer). However, inheritance stands out as something which almost every experienced programmer will advice against.

The mantra here is to always use object composition instead of inheritance whenever possible (which, in my opinion, is practically always the case).

This is different from, say, modeling a proper type system on top of JavaScript. Or, modeling deconstruction and structural pattern matching. Those toys might also never be used in production, but at least you'll build something that you'll later actually want to use "for real".

Note that inheritance didn't hold its promises in any language, be it C++, Python, Ruby, PHP, Smalltalk, Java, and so on. You can find early hints even in the GoF book (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), which is a kind-of bible for most OO programmers. There, although inheritance is not criticized directly, you can summarize a whole subsection of patterns as "how to replace a hard-to-maintain inheritance structure with a well-maintainable structure of object composition".

Comment: _"inheritance is a well-known anti-pattern"_, only in javascript, right?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir No, in general. I improved my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure what object composition is, but if I had to guess I'd say it was an alternative pattern of class extension / instantiation to the linear one that I have authored in this question, where-in I would have to assume some form of inheritance was taking place anyway. I of course am not prepared to embrace one pattern over another as I'm am simply trying to understand how the mechanism that makes these patterns viable practices in the first place even works.

Comment: -1 for not answering the question at all. Also, inheritance is not an antipattern in general, it just is a pattern that doesn't apply everywhere and is often overused. It's still valid to use in many, many cases, and especially in JavaScript we hardly can do anything without objects that inherit from some prototype.